# Flutter Location Package is Not Working in App Release Mode

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages

Flutter App is working fine with Location Package in Debug Mode but it is not working in Release Mode, the app is not giving location access. i tried to use Flutter Clean Command but nothing Helped. Pls Help me

Comment: You need to provide your code.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is that the flutter build (APK, bundle) isn't making API calls in a real device, this is because you need to add the Internet permission to Android Manifest before creating the release/build.

By default, "internet use" will work fine on the emulator but not on a real device.

To fix this, simply:

Open the file "android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" and add the proper user-permission

```
<manifest> 
...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
...
</manifest>
```

And then create your build again.
Also  there is discussion on github , you can visit their and clearify your problem more effectively [Github](http://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20789).